# Many to Many in database first approach mvc crud operation

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-database-first

How to use many to many relationship in mvc database first approach. I am having following table structure in sql

Table 1:- studentMaster
Table 2:- Subjects

My Model1.edmx and sql table structure pic is here

http://geeksprogrammings.blogspot.com/2014/04/blog-post.html

I know how to perform CRUD operation using Entity Framework using DAtabase First approach but how to perform crud operation when table have many to many relationship . I have also put my question on codeproject but no proper help is given

Comment: which code ......actually i don't know how to perform crud operation when there is many2many relationship between tables in database

Comment: A many-to-many relationship needs to be projected to two many-to-one relationships.
StudentMaster(StudentId)
Subjects(SubjectId)
StudentMaster_RELATIONSHIP_Subject(StudentId, SubjectId, POSSIBLE META DATA)

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Liam, my question is just how to insert,delete,edit,update data in tables when tables are having many 2 many relationship ......I am using Entity framework database first approach

Comment: Follow the Blog for MVC Crud Operation with Interfaces and Repository Pattern with ADO.Net
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/MVC-Crud-Operation-with-Interfaces-and-Repository-Pattern-with-ADONet

Answer (score 2):

if not using any kind of IRepository pattern:

**Create**

Adding new student with subjects

```
using(var dbContext = new Model1Entitites()){
  var student = new Student{details..};
  student.Add(new Subject{});
  dbContext.Students.Add(student);
  dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Update**
Adding subjects to an existing student

```
using(var dbContext = new Model1Entities()){
    objectToAddTo = dbContext.studentMaster.SingleOrDefault(x=> x.id == id);
    objectToAddTo.Subjects.Add(new Subject{});
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Adding existing subjects to an existing student

```
var student = db.Students.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Id == id);
var subjectToAdd = db.Subjects.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.id == SubjectId);

if(student!= null){
    if(subjectToAdd != null){
       student.Subjects.Add(subjectToAdd);
    }
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

**Remove subject from student**

```
using(var dbContext = new Model1Entities()){
    objectToRemoveFrom = dbContext.studentMaster.SingleOrDefault(x=> x.id == id);
    var subjectToRemove = dbContext.Subjects.SingleOrDefault(x=> x.subjectid==subjectid);
    objectToRemoveFrom.Subjects.Remove(subject);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Select**

```
using(var dbContext = new Model1Entities()){
    return dbContext.Students.Include(x=> x.Subjects);
}
```

For adding multiple connections the other way around, do the same with the other object.

**Returning something to view when dealing with connections**

Since razor is not always happy with getting entities containing connection entitites, you should probably create a new model for the view instead of using the entity proxy.

**Controller**

```
var model = new StudentModel();
var student = db.Students.Include(x=> x.Subjects);
//here you can use example AutoMapper, or you can do it manually
model.Id = student.id;
model.Name = student.Name;
model.Subjects = db.Students.Subjects.Select(x=> new SubjectModel{Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name}).ToList();
return View(model);
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class StudentModel{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public List<SubjectModel> Subjects{get;set;}
}
public class SubjectModel{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

**Razor**

```
@model StudentModel;

<span>Student name @Model.Name</span>

<ul>

    @foreach(var subject in Model.Subjects){
       <li id="@subject.Id">@subject.Name</li>
    }
<ul>
```

Comment: i am unable to get how to use this code do you have any example

Comment: I though i gave you an example;) 

Handling many to many relationships is no different than all other crud operations. Which operations do you want example code for?

Comment: i want to code for view student with course

Comment: That's code to show student details with subjects which model class should i add to view . If i add only student class then subjects are not shown and i want students with their subjects
 public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View(db.StudentMasters .Include(x => x.Subjects ));
        }

Comment: Ah, see your point. Ill post an example

Comment: yes,  my problem is how i can pass multiple model to view or is it possible

Comment: like in code below  if I add view with scaffolding list then it only shows student data not subjects


return View(db.StudentMasters .Include(x => x.Subjects ));

Comment: In below line there is error and model does not have anything like Students----------

model.Students = db.Students.Subjects.Select(x=> new StudentModel{Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name}).ToList();

Comment: My bad, should be model.Subjects. Typo

Comment: yes, but still it gives error at these lines -------

Comment: model.Id = student.id;----- error at id

Comment: error at name-------
model.Name = student.Name;

Comment: error at subjects in  db.StudentMasters .Subjects---------------------------

 model.Subjects = db.StudentMasters .Subjects.Select(x => new StudentModel { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name }).ToList();

Comment: Since i have no idea what your entity names are, i just assumed that Id and Name was in there. You of course like always have to adjust the code to fit your needs.

Comment: but no entity names comes when i pres dot(.) after model

Comment: I have adjusted code like this Is it right  ------------------
var model = new StudentModel();---------------
            var student = db.StudentMasters  .Include(x => x.Subjects);--------------------
            //here you can use example AutoMapper, or you can do it manually
            model.Id = 2;------------------
            model.Name = "HB";-----------------
            model.Subjects = db.Subjects.Select(x => new -----------SubjectModel  { Id = x.SubjectID , Name = x.SubjectName  }).ToList();---------------------------
            return View(model);-----------------

Comment: Remember that studentMasters is containing more than one entry. 

db.StudentMasters.Include(x=> x.Subjects).FirstOrDefault() will fetch the first record.

db.StudentMasters.Include(x=> x.Subjects).FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Id == 1); will fetch the first record that has the Id == 1

Comment: Is my code correct.............I have not added view untill as your view code gives errors

Comment: printing model in razor should be Model, fixed it in my solution.

Comment: Correct Controller code :-
 var model = new viewmodel.StudentModel();----------------------
            var student = db.StudentMasters.Include(x => x.Subjects);-------------------------
            //here you can use example AutoMapper, or you can do it manually
            model.Id = 2;----------------------
            model.Name = "HB";----------------------------
            model.Subjects = db.Subjects.Select(x => new viewmodel . SubjectModel  { Id = x.SubjectID , Name = x.SubjectName  }).ToList();------------------------------------
            return View(model);--------------------

Comment: could you plz explain this line -------------especially -----Id = x.SubjectID , Name = x.SubjectName---------------

model.Subjects = db.Subjects.Select(x => new viewmodel . SubjectModel  { Id = x.SubjectID , Name = x.SubjectName  }).ToList();

Comment: new viewmodel should be New SubjectModel

Comment: But my viewmodel structure is like studentmodel and subjectmodel class are under viewmodl class and are placed on controller not separate

Comment: If you use StudentModel as the viewmodel, and applies the SubjectModels like in my example. Its gonna work just fine.

Comment: now it works .......but it shows student name with all subject names in subject table. But it should show only subject assigned to that student

Comment: There is problem in you update code when we use update code it add new subject to subject everytime but I have to use existing subjects

Comment: You have to fetch the existing subjects from db and add them to the student object when doing the update.

Comment: IF i want to staically give id of subject to add to student's subjects

Comment: My update works but every time it adds new subject--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
My insert works student works but everytime it adds new subject
-------------------------------------------------------------
My select works but it retrieve all subjects instead of only subjects related to specific student

Comment: You have to provide code if something doesnt work. Please create a new thread to get more help. I cant write your entire application for you.

Comment: ok, thanks for great help

Comment: Follow the Blog for MVC Crud Operation with Interfaces and Repository Pattern with ADO.Net
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/MVC-Crud-Operation-with-Interfaces-and-Repository-Pattern-with-ADONet